# Nlog to write each Request/Session data combined

Tags: c#, .net, nlog

i have a REST service and i want to write each request data combined like

- Request1 - data
- Request1 - data
- Request2 - data
- Request2 - data

Currently each request data overlaps like

- Request1 - data
- Request2 - data
- Request1 - data
- Request2 - data

Comment: Write - where? Console? File? DB?

Comment: @Fildor i am wring to File

Comment: You could accumulate data and write them all at once ( in one call to Log.Info() for example). I presently don't know if there is a methodology in NLog to bundle Log messages like that,

Comment: Yeah i was thinking of doing that by creating a dictionary of requestid paired with stringbuffer and dumping them after request completion at once, i just thought there might be a way of doing this by Nlog configuration which seems there isn't